# How to create a dynamic drop list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, dropdown

I've got a spreadsheet that I'm trying to create a dynamic drop list in. I have it setup so that I have a list of `Test No.` and the Day of the week next to it. It looks like this:

[image: Setup TestNumbers]

Now what I want is as I add the same number under one of the lists I want the drop down list to only give me the available days that are not already used for that number.

i.e. for `1234` the drop down under New should have Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun
i.e. for `5678` the drop down under New should have Mon, Wed, Thu, Sat, Sun
i.e. for `9012` the drop down under New should have tue, Sat, Sun

I have a named range that has the 7 days of the week and I can use Data Validation to have that list be the drop options, but I want it to be dynamic and only give me the options that are not already used by that `Test No`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in Columns A:B where row1 is header row and you have a named range called **Days** then right click the Sheet tab --> View code and paste the code given below into the opened code window --> Save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long, lr As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim Str As String
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A2:A" & lr)
x = Range("Days").Value
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    If Target.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
        For Each Cell In Rng
            If Cell <> "" And Cell = Target.Offset(0, -1) Then
                If Str = "" Then
                    Str = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Else
                    Str = Str & ", " & Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
        For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            If InStr(Str, x(i, 1)) = 0 Then
                dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
        On Error Resume Next
        With Target.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                                xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(dict.keys, ",")
        End With
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

So once you select a cell in column B, the code will add a drop down list excluding the days already selected for the specific test no. corresponding cell in column A.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event in the sheet's code module to change the validation list. Some checks are necessary to see if the new selected cell is one of those you want to validate; i.e. column B, an identifier in column A, etc. The checks in the routine below conform to your example data.

```
' Code Module of your worksheet
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 2 Or Target.row < 2 Then Exit Sub
    If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) > 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Len(Trim(Target.offset(, -1).Value)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim newList As String: newList = ",Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat"
    Dim r As Range: Set r = Target.offset(-1)
    Do Until Len(Trim(r.Value2)) = 0 Or r.offset(, -1).Value2 <> Target.offset(, -1).Value2
        newList = Replace(newList, "," & r.Value2, "")
        Set r = r.offset(-1)
    Loop
    With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add xlValidateList, , , Mid(newList, 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use depending Drop Down List
Create your List Mon--Sunday Define Name **wkday** for example
Select Tue--Sunday and Define Name **Mon**
Select Wed--Sunday and Define Name **Tue**
Select Thu--Sunday and Define Name **Wed**
Select Fri--Sunday and Define Name **Thu**
Select Sat--Sunday and Define Name **Fri**
Select Sunday and Define Name **Sat**

You can select all the cells in which you need the Drop Down List:
Starting with Cell B2 for example below create Data Validation, List, in Source write:

`=IF(OR(B1="",B1="Day"),wkday,INDIRECT(B1))`

Comment: This would only cover it if they are always picked in order. sometimes they are not like with `9012` it is picked with Mon then Wed, so I would need Tue, Sat, Sun in the drop down at the end.

Comment: If you choose Wed under Mon, the cell below will list Thu--Sunday (Name Wed)